# Hashmap within ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

There is a hash map within the ArrayList. the output is like below

```
[{A=2},{A=3},{B=1},{B=4},{A=3}]
```

Below I have mentioned my code sample

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Short>> deviceInfo = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Integer> rssiMapper = new HashMap<>();

rssiMapper.put(device.getName(), rssi);
deviceInfo.add(rssiMapper);
```

I want to take mean value of A and B separately. How can I achieve that

Comment: Can you share the code of the List of Map, and what have you tried ?

Comment: updated with some code. actually I am scanning Bluetooth devices and take device names and RSSI within a specific distance. I want to take the average value of RSSI, that what I am trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create maps to track the `sum`, `count` and the `mean` (i.e. `sum / count`) of the entries as shown below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, Integer>> list = List.of(Map.of("A", 2), Map.of("A", 3), Map.of("B", 1), Map.of("B", 4),
                Map.of("A", 3));
        Map<String, Integer> sumMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Double> meanMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map<String, Integer> map : list) {
            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                sumMap.put(entry.getKey(), sumMap.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0) + entry.getValue());
                countMap.put(entry.getKey(), countMap.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0) + 1);
                meanMap.put(entry.getKey(),
                        (double) sumMap.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0) / countMap.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 1));
            }
        }

        // Display
        System.out.println(meanMap);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{A=2.6666666666666665, B=2.5}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this.

```
List<Map<String,Integer>> list = List.of(
    Map.of("A", 2),
    Map.of("A", 3),
    Map.of("B", 1),
    Map.of("B", 4),
    Map.of("A", 3));

Map<String, Double> avgs = list.stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.averagingInt(Entry::getValue)));
System.out.println(avgs);
```

Prints

```
{A=2.6666666666666665, B=2.5}
```

As was suggested, if you are unfamiliar with streams, here is an iterative approach.

```
Map<String,Double> avgs = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String,Integer> map : list) {
     for (Entry<String,Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
         String key = e.getKey();
         int value = e.getValue();
         // These just either initialize or update the appropriate
         // values.
         avgs.compute(key, (k,v)-> v == null ? value : v + value);
         count.compute(key, (k,v)->v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
     }
}
// now find the averages.
for(Entry<String,Double> e : avgs.entrySet()) {
    avgs.computeIfPresent(e.getKey(), (k,v)->v/count.get(e.getKey()));
}

System.out.println(avgs);
```

Comment: Should use `Entry::getKey` and `Entry::getValue` instead of `e->e.getKey()` and `e->e.getValue()`.

Comment: Is one really better than the other in terms of generated code?

Comment: This could potentially be too advanced for a random reader. Might be good to also provide a non-stream solution next to this.

Comment: Yes. `e->e.getKey()` has to create a hidden method in the current class with the lambda expression as the method body. `Entry::getKey` does not need that, i.e. less code.

Comment: @andreas  Good to know.  I did not know that.